# Eclipse Kepler, Tomcat 6/7, on Windows 7, application loading in /Users/<MyUser>/AppData/Local/Temp/*

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat

Hello good afternoon my project have recently upgraded our local dev environment from Windows Xp / Tomcat 5 / Eclipse Helius to Windows 7 / Tomcat 7 / Eclipse Kepler.

We make use of the plugin to integrate Tomcat into Eclipse and launch the server from Eclipse. The plugin is configured to Use Tomcat Installation and deploy to dir: `wtpwebapps`.
The problem is that this configuration seems to be ignored and the web app is being launched from `C:/Users/582027/AppData/Local/Temp/0-glad-presentation/`.
On top of that the static content, so html and js code for example isn't being refresh while server is running.

The following log is an example of that.

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[main][19/05/2014 17:46:46][INFO ][      ][ContextLoader:initWebApplicationContext] - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[main][19/05/2014 17:46:47][INFO ][      ][XmlWebApplicationContext:prepareRefresh] - Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@b05acd: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Mon May 19 17:46:47 BST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
[main][19/05/2014 17:46:47][INFO ][      ][XmlBeanDefinitionReader:loadBeanDefinitions] - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/582027/AppData/Local/Temp/0-glad-presentation/WEB-INF/lib/glad-core-6.0.0.9.jar!/com/bnpparibas/glad/applicationContext.xml]
[main][19/05/2014 17:46:47][INFO ][      ][XmlBeanDefinitionReader:loadBeanDefinitions] - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/582027/AppData/Local/Temp/0-glad-presentation/WEB-INF/lib/glad-dao-6.0.0.9.jar!/com/bnpparibas/glad/dao/daoContext.xml]
```

Have some had a problem similar to this? 
Maybe windows 7 policies or something like that?

Thanks and Regards,
Luís Caracol

Comment: Does the problem also exist when you use `Use custom location` instead? Also, where is you Tomcat installation (did you let Eclipse download/install it when adding a server runtime)? Maybe there is some crazy symlink or whatever which points to this temp folder.

Comment: Hello, my tomcat is in this location: C:\Tools\apache-tomcat-7.0.52 and i have installed it "by hand". I just said Eclipse to use that location. Same thing happens when i use custom location.